# Python subprocess Help

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm testing python subprocess and I keep getting this error:

```
$ python subprocess-test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subprocess-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-azP', 'rsync://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/daily-live/current/maverick-desktop-amd64.iso', '/home/roaksoax/Desktop/iso'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

My script is:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-azP', 'rsync://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/daily-live/current/maverick-desktop-amd64.iso', '/home/testing/maverick.iso'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Do you guys know what might be happening?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: subprocess is in python since 2.4, if an older version of python would be used, the error should already occur during the import statement.

Comment: @Fabian: That's true, but it's a good thing to specify in the question in any case.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Wild guess: you have your own file called subprocess.py which is masking the standard library module.

What do you see with this?:

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.__file__
```

This will show what file is being imported as `subprocess`.

Comment: This was indeed the problem! Thank you!!